# How to distribute windows over virtual desktops in Gnome

Tags: gnome, window-manager, metacity

I have a load of virtual desktops running and I usually have one full screen application per desktop (so sort of like the Ratpoison WM but with an option to use it in other ways when needed). I want new windows to automatically be put in certain desktop numbers when they start up. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Compiz, install `compizconfig-settings-manager`, activate the "Place Windows" plugin, and in the "Fixed Window Placement" tab, you can adjust which windows should default to which viewport.

Comment: +1 for `fixed window placement`. Easiest solution for any compiz user. This tab is found in the configuration for the `Place Windows` plugin under the `Window management` category. Of course, `Place Windows` needs to be enabled for this to work.

Comment: I'm confused about `viewports` and `workspaces` -- What I see in the `fixed window placement` tab is X/Y viewport coordinates that don't seem to correlate to my four workspaces.

Comment: I don't see a `Fixed Window Placement` tab...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Devil's Pie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) tool; it is available in Ubuntu as package `devilspie` (`apt-get install devilspie`).

[This article](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/122471) and [this other one](http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie) explain some of its prominent features, and provides some example code, including how to move a window to a certain workspace and maximize it.

Comment: You can also [click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/devilspie) to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I, too have a lot of virtual desktops and a workflow that has me opening windows on different workspaces, but I've adopted an 'open and slide' approach with compiz.. right after opening an application, I use a customized shortcut to slide the new window to the appropriate workspace, then slide back to the previous workspace with another shortcut.

In my case, this is something like shift-ctrl-left arrow then ctrl-alt-right arrow.. very, very quick and I have full control over where they go every time instead of being locked-in to one configuration.

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement can make use of scripts, then it might be worth investigating wmctrl eg `wmctrl -s 0` would switch to desktop 0.