# Is it possible to pin certain apps to a workspace in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distribute windows over virtual desktops in Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6422/how-to-distribute-windows-over-virtual-desktops-in-gnome)

Is there a way to assign apps to a specific workspace in Unity (11.10)? With this I mean that when I open, for instance Rhythmbox, it allways opens in Workspace 2. When I click on LibreOffice Writer in the dock, it opens in workspace 4. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager using

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run it by searching for **ccsm** in Dash, and scroll down to **Place Windows** under Window Management. Check it, click it and move to the **Fixed Window Placement** tab. Under **Windows with Fixed Viewports**, click **New**. Click the big, green **Plus** sign to the right. Leave the dropdown menu to Window Class to get all instances of the program to run in same workspace.* Click **Grab** and point the cross-hair to the application you would like to set the option for. Click the app. Then set the grid location and you should be done!

*: I'm unsure of the effect of the other options, but on thing that can be annoying with the window class option is that if you move your application to a different workspace after you have opened it, then any dialogs will still open in the set workspace. It can be confusing.