# Is it possible to pin programs to specific workspaces, without CCSM?

Tags: compiz, workspaces, devilspie, gdevilspie

I'm running 11.10.

Is there a way of setting certain applications to always open on a specified workspace?
I have noticed that most people suggest using CompizConfig Settings Manager, but this can cause disastrous problems with Unity.

I found this identical question, but the only answer there was CCSM:
[Is it possible to pin certain apps to a workspace in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85428/is-it-possible-to-pin-certain-apps-to-a-workspace-in-unity)

Is there any way to do this without CCSM? I have been searching for ages, but can't find an alternative.

**EDIT:**

Devilspie partially works, but appears to have some limitations.
I have a 2x2 workspace grid and can successfully get applications to start in workspace 1 or two, but trying 3 or 4 fails and the application loads in workspace 1.
This seems to be an issue with them being on a second row.
I have found many others with the same issue, such as here:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/devilspie-and-compiz-viewports-on-multiple-rows-860619/

Where the suggested answer was to use CCSM!

Comment: Did you try "set_viewport" instead of "set_workspace"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can use Devilspie to do that. There is a GUI for this app too. Follow these steps:

**1)** Install: `sudo apt-get install devilspie gdevilspie`

**2)** Open gdevilspie.

**3)** Start the daemon:

[image]

**4)** Select the matching window:

[image]

**5)** Choose the workspace:

[image]

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: hmm.. after looking into devilspie, it does seem to work, partially. See my edit in the original post for an explanation.

Comment: Did you try "set_viewport" instead of "set_workspace"?

Comment: unfortunately it seems to be affected by a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdevilspie/+bug/1161594