# How do I make resizing dialogues and windows stick permanently?

Tags: window-manager, window, resize

On my netbook with a resolution of 1024x768, dialogues, like "file open" dialogue or "windows", like the file manager window are opened so that the height of the dialogue/window is too huge.

Every time, I have to press the 
<kbd>alt</kbd> button, move the dialogue/window and resize it, to use it normally.
Something that is really anoying, especially, because Ubuntu already knows (like I can see in the dash - that is set to netbook) about the monitor form factor. All the netbooks have a display 1024x576 or 1024x600 - so it would be nice, if the dialogues would be resized to not extent over the borders.

Another option would be, if I could resize dialogues/windows - and "save" the form after it, so next time, it would open with exactly the new size. I tried the <kbd>F5</kbd> button - but that is not a solution.
So I'd ask, if anyone knows a solution to solve this unlucky behaviour.

Comment: That would be a nice feature.  I hope someone fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you are willing to devote some time to it, I'm afraid. Bug reports to the programs would be a good first step, though.

As a workaround, you can use devilspie as outlined  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102616/is-it-possible-to-pin-programs-to-specific-workspaces-without-ccsm/), but by setting the size of the window instead ofthe workspace.

A simple script invoked via a hotkey that uses wmctrl could also do the trick.

But I still think you should make feature request bug reports, so that this type of ugly hack is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, Lakritsbollar,

I already reported now the two anonying bugs with netbooks and Unity.

This one here: [Dialogue boxes are to huge on somes screens (like netbooks) and can't saved resized for the next time](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/944973)


and that one: [The top panel of Unity can become too small, so that the handling is unpredictable (like on netbooks)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/944991)