# Remember gnome-terminal position across multiple desktop after reboot

Tags: gnome, command-line, gnome-terminal, gnome2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pin programs to specific workspaces, without CCSM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102616/is-it-possible-to-pin-programs-to-specific-workspaces-without-ccsm)

I work with several virtual desktop (Gnome desktop) and several terminal with several tab in each terminal. 
How to remember the position, size, current directories of all this when reboot ?

Comment: I don't have a complete solution, but you could loop over `xdotool search --name Terminal`, get the size with `xwininfo -size`, and create a script based on those which you could run to restore the settings.